# Adding items to listbox from excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, listbox

I have a column in an Excel file that contain 100 rows. I'm trying to import this column into a ListBox using a button.

The problem is that only 48 rows are importing from the Excel column.

Why aren't all the rows inside the column imported?

Here is my code (vb.net form):

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.xlsx")
    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As String
    For i = 0 To AscW(ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1
        'set cell name, e.g. A1, A2, etc
        cell = "B" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
        ' get cell data from Excel
        cell = oSheet.Range(cell).Value
        If cell = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            ListBox5.Items.Add(cell)
        End If
    Next
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an empty cell??? `If cell = "" Then` `Exit For`

Comment: The issue is most probably coming from `AscW(ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1` or the `Exit For`, why are you taking the Asc value of your listbox's count?

Comment: there is no empty cell, I'm using Asc to take all the items not a specific size

Comment: is there any alternative way to implement it ? @R3uK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your `AscW(...` to `oSheet.Range("B" & oSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, 
so that you'll add all the column B to your ListBox

(still, be careful because of your `Exit For` you canNOT have an empty cell in the middle!)

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.xlsx")
    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As String
For i = 0 To oSheet.Range("B" & oSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'set cell name, e.g. A1, A2, etc
    cell = "B" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
    ' get cell data from Excel
    cell = oSheet.Range(cell).Value
    If cell = "" Then
        Exit For
    Else
        ListBox5.Items.Add (cell)
    End If
Next i
oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Very much appreciate your answer . But a small error occur ( Error 'xlup' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level)

Comment: Ok, so you can replace it by its actual value : `Const xlUp = -4162 (&HFFFFEFBE)`, let me know if it is enough! ;)

Comment: Can you be more specific where exactly to insert the actual value?

Comment: You could either define a variable with that name and set it to the good value. Or you can just replace it directly in the line `For i = ...` , change `).End(xlUp).` to `).End(-4162).`

Comment: Thank alot.. You are my life saver. A little small question.. what if i want to include the last row ?

Comment: Strange that you don't already get the very last row... Try to add `+ 1` at the of this line : `For i = 0 To oSheet.Range("B" & oSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @bod : Btw, could you please "help" me too, could you DOWNvote this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34272756/4628637

Comment: Ofcourse i would love to help you .. but i can't downvote now until the answer is edited

Comment: Thx! I did it. Did my suggestion solved your last row issue?

Comment: @bod : Glad we solved all of this! And thx for future downvote! :)