# VB.NET has stopped working with an excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have an excel sheet feeding a vb.net project.The excel sheet has a column of data that is downloaded into alist box on my vb form.
This was working fine until for no particular reason the excel sheet decided to become a read only file,this meant I could not update the Excel sheets for my program,and it would not let me delete or modify in any way.
I tried all of the various methods to unlock the including starting in safe mode and deleting then starting again.I also tried renaming the file but this was totally inpractical because I would have to replace the name in the code of my vb project everytime I wanted to update the Excel sheet.
When I reboot my computer,the excel file appears as normal and all modification privelages return.
I then open vb.net and everything workrd fine in the sense that the Excel sheet downloads perfectly into the vb.net program.At this point however (after running vb.net program once or several times) if I try to open the Excel file I get the box up stating that the "File Is Now Available" box stating that my file is now "available for editing" and to "Choose Read-Write to open for editing"..of course If I choose Read_Write I am taken back to the excel file but am unable to modify iy in any way.When I eventually get rid of this irritating boc(it seems to multiply all on its own,the click on the excel file,the file flashes up for a split second on the screen then promptly disapears.
If I reboot everything goes back to normal and the whole process is repeated of I try and modify the excel file in any way.
Here is the code I use to download the dat from excel into my list box in VB.net
I can only assume that the vb program violates excel in some way.

```
Private Sub Button28_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button28.Click
    Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ dave\Desktop\exammark.xlsm")
    Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As String
    For i = 0 To AscW(studentList.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1
        'set cell name, e.g. A1, A2, etc
        cell = "I" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
        ' get cell data from Excel
        cell = oSheet.Range(cell).Value
        If cell = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            studentList.Items.Add(cell)
        End If
    Next
    oExcel.workbooks.close()
    oExcel.Quit()
```

Comment: Type `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.  Then fix the errors.  This may not fix the locking problem, but that code has some severe issues in the For-Next declaration.

Comment: Probably the way you use cell as range, then assign a value, and then use it as a range again could cause problems.

Comment: Are you using `vb.net` (e.g. in a development environment like Visual Studio) or `vba` in Excel itself? Important question, because trying to force open a file when called by itself in another instance of Excel is likely to have very interesting effects - including locking the file, causing task-level conflicts in the operating system and potentially corrupting it!

Comment: I am using vb.net from inside the visual studio,but I got the original code from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308648/adding-items-to-listbox-from-excel